# Change the values of all nested objects Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

reducer looks like this

```
import {ADD_TASK, EDIT_TASK, CHECK_TASK, CHECK_ALL_TASK} from '../constants';
import {OrderedMap, Record} from 'immutable';

const TaskRecord = Record({
    id: null,
    text: null,
    isChecked: false
});

const ReducerState = Record({
    entities: new OrderedMap({})
});

const defaultState = new ReducerState();

export default (tasksState = defaultState, action) => {
    const {type, payload, randomId} = action;

    switch (type) {
        case ADD_TASK:
            return tasksState.setIn(['entities', randomId], new TaskRecord({...payload.task, id: randomId}));
        case CHECK_ALL_TASK:
            return tasksState.map(entities => {
                return entities.map((task) => {
                    task.set('isChecked', true);
                });
            });
    };

    return tasksState;
};
```

How change all isChecked in TaskRecord that in entities? I wrote CHECK_ALL_TASK, but it gives an error (tasksState undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to set a new value for a property based on it's current one, `.update` is what you want to use.
When you want to make a change to each item in a collection, `.map` is what you want to use.
In your case, you want to set a new value for the property `entities` by modifying each entity in the collection.
This means you want to use `update` and `map`:

```
function checkAllBoxes(taskState) {
  return taskState.update('entities', entities => 
    entities.map(entity =>
      entity.set('isChecked', true)));
}
```

```js
const TaskRecord = Immutable.Record({
  id: null,
  text: null,
  isChecked: false
});

const ReducerState = Immutable.Record({
  entities: new Immutable.OrderedMap({})
});

const taskState = new ReducerState({
  entities: Immutable.OrderedMap({
    a: new TaskRecord(),
    b: new TaskRecord(),
    c: new TaskRecord()
  })
});

function checkAllBoxes(taskState) {
  return taskState.update('entities', entities =>
    entities.map(entity =>
      entity.set('isChecked', true)));
}

console.log(checkAllBoxes(taskState))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrote this function, but can it be made as something simpler?

```
function checkAllCheckboxes(state) {
    let newState = state;
    for (let id of state.entities) {
        newState = newState.setIn(['entities', id[0], 'isChecked'], true);
    }
    return newState;
}
```